# Split the camel cased sentence into words

Tags: oracle, regexp-replace

I need to split the camel cased sentence into words using SQL.

**Example:** `'IHaveAPen'` into `'I Have A Pen'`

I'm using the `regex`

```
select regexp_replace('IAmGoodBoy','([^^])(A-Z)','\1 \2 \3') from dual;
```

to split strings by capital letter.

but it doesn't work.

Can this be done?

Comment: `regexp_replace('IAmGoodBoy','([A-Z])',' \1')` would work. [Demo Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/38969).  it just appends a space to every capital letter.

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar Your solution starts with a space so it actually prepends a space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with the following query:

```
select regexp_replace('IAmGoodBoy','([A-Z][^A-Z]*)','\1 ') from dual;
```